# How To Set select box value change to textbox color change

Tags: jquery, css

i want to Select box value change to textbox background color change

```
<select id="color">
     <option value="Black">Black</option>
     <option value="White">White</option>
     <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
     <option value="Green">Green</option>
     <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="color" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="amount" value=""/>
```

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question, such as exactly what you're trying to achieve. Your question currently makes no sense.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcqhpuoj/3 UseFul This

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want, but try check this out :

**HTML**

```
<select id="color">
 <option value="Black">Black</option>
 <option value="White">White</option>
 <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
 <option value="Green">Green</option>
 <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="color" value="" id="textColor"/>
<input type="text" name="amount" value=""/>
```

**JS**

```
// use id color as a selector
// and register change event to it
$('#color').change(function(){
  $('[name="color"]').css('background',$(this).val()); 
  // if wanna change color for all input use below code
  // $('input').css('background',$(this).val());  
  // or reference it by id like below
  // $('#textColor').css('background',$(this).val()); 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/0fsp0bx5/)**

Check this link for references

1. https://api.jquery.com/change/
2. http://api.jquery.com/css/
3. http://jsfiddle.net/Lcqhpuoj/3 - Question's answer.

Comment: Avoid using attribute selector ,they are one of the slowest .instead you can use id selector,as it is the fastest when it comes to traversing the dom. https://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2

Comment: Yeah, just wanna make real example related with relevant code posted by OP.  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like :

**Your HTML**

```
<select id="color">
 <option value="Black">Black</option>
 <option value="White">White</option>
 <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
 <option value="Green">Green</option>
 <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#color").change(function(){
   var color=$(this).val();
   $("input[type=text]").css("background-color",color);
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ahsvkrn7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just try with the JQuery:

```
<select id="color">
     <option value="Black">Black</option>
     <option value="White">White</option>
     <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
     <option value="Green">Green</option>
     <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="color" value="" id = "text1"/>
<input type="text" name="amount" value="" id = "text2"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
$("select#yourSelect").change(function(){
$('#text1').val($(this).val());
$('#text2').val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```